# Utility Application Template: How to refresh a UIPickerView from flipside view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using the Utility Application Template with Core Data. In the flipside view, user can add items and these items brand and model feed a UIPickerView on the main view.

When the user adds an item, unless she or he closes the app this added item does not appear in the picker row titles.

How can I load this title without closing the app? 
Thanks

Edit to add code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //retrieving data from iGear.xcdatamodeld
    iGearAppDelegate *iGearDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [iGearDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    if (managedObjectContext !=nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && [managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            //NSLog(@"Retrieving: unresolved error %@, %@",error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
         }
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cogset"     inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

//#pragma mark UIPickerView

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
 {
    return [fetchedObjects count];
 }

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) 
    {
        cogset = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",cogset.brand,cogset.model];
    }
    return @"";
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    cassette = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:[_chooseCogsetPickerView  selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a `UIPickerViewDelegate` for your UIPickerView.

Then, use this delegate function to populate your picker view:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component ]
{
 return someValue;
}
```

I can try to help you more specifically if you post some actual code with what's currently happening.

Comment: Titles on PickerView are displayed correctly, but the case is, I need to refresh the main view, or at leat, use the "-(void)viewWillAppear" method. If the app runs on an iPhone, there's no problem, but on an iPad, users add data on a popover. Maybe I shoud change this popover into a modal view...